# Using C# code Get Distinct values from MongoDB array where it is matching some values specifically

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am new to the MongoDB. I have one document named `Documents` in which I have multiple data as mentioned below

Data 1 -

```
{
    "ProjId": 18586,
    "ArtifactAttributes": [
        {
            
            "AttributeName": "Author",
            "AttributeValue": "XYZ"
            
        },
        {
            
            "AttributeName": "Address",
            "AttributeValue": "Addrr1"
            
        },
        {
            
            "AttributeName": "Owner",
            "AttributeValue": "manoj.naik"
            
        }
    ]
}
```

Data 2 -

```
{
    "ProjId": 18587,
    "ArtifactAttributes": [
        {
            
            "AttributeName": "Author",
            "AttributeValue": "ABC"
            
        },
        {
            
            "AttributeName": "Address",
            "AttributeValue": "Addrr2"
            
        },
        {
            
            "AttributeName": "Owner",
            "AttributeValue": "kumar.manoj"
            
        }
    ]
}
```

Data - 3

```
{
    "ProjId": 18588,
    "ArtifactAttributes": [
        {
            
            "AttributeName": "Author",
            "AttributeValue": "PQR"
            
        },
        {
            
            "AttributeName": "Address",
            "AttributeValue": "Addrr3"
            
        },
        {
            
            "AttributeName": "Owner",
            "AttributeValue": "kumar.manoj"
            
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to return distinct value where `AttributeName` is equals to `Owner`.

Expected Result - `[manoj.naik,kumar.manoj]`

For that I have written code as below but it is not returning expected result instead of that it is returning all distinct values from `AttributeValue` not specifically from `AttributeName` where it has `Owner`

Result which I am getting is as below

```
[XYZ,Addrr1,manoj.naik,ABC,Addrr2,kumar.manoj,PQR,Addrr3]
```

My C# Code -

```
var ownerFilter = Builders<Documents>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.ArtifactAttributes, p => p.AttributeName.Equals("Owner"));
var ownerValueFieldDefinition = new StringFieldDefinition<Documents, string>("ArtifactAttributes.AttributeValue");
var distinctItems = _projectArtifacts.Distinct(ownerValueFieldDefinition, ownerFilter).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because `ElemMatch` matches any document that has an element with `AttributeName == "Owner"` in its `ArtifactAttributes`. It returns original unmodified documents, it doesn't magically remove values of `ArtifactAttributes` that you don't need.

As far as I know, there is no elegant way to do what you want, but you can do this:

```
var distinctItems = _projectArtifacts
    .Aggregate()
    .Unwind(x => x.ArtifactAttributes)
    .Match(x => x["ArtifactAttributes.AttributeName"] == "Owner")
    .Group("{ _id: '$ArtifactAttributes.AttributeValue' }")
    .ToList()
    .Select(x => x["_id"].AsString)
    .ToList();
```

Step-by-step explanation:

1. `Aggregate` - start an aggregation pipeline.
2. `Unwind` - replace each document with its copies, each containing only one of the values of `ArtifactAttributes`.
3. `Match` - filter documents, leaving only those where `AttributeName == "Owner"`.
4. `Group` - group documents by `AttributeValue`. This allows to get all the distinct values in the `_id` field.
5. `ToList` - get results from the database. Aggregation always returns a list of documents, not just values. So you have to do some more steps to get list of values.
6. `Select` and `ToList` - get list of values using LINQ.

Comment: thanks. I tried  var ownerData = _projectArtifacts.Aggregate()
                .Unwind(doc => doc.ArtifactAttributes)
              .ReplaceRoot<ArtifactAttributes>("$ArtifactAttributes")
                .Match(attr => attr.AttributeName.Equals("Owner") && attr.AttributeValue != null && attr.AttributeValue != "")
                .Project(b => new ArtifactAttributes { AttributeValue = b.AttributeValue})
              .ToList();
     
     var ownerList = ownerData.Select(x => x.AttributeValue).Distinct().Where(y => y != null).OrderBy(p => p).ToList(); this one and it was working.

Comment: But you answer is more reliable hence i will go with that